# How to resolve issues when uploading iphone app to app store?

Tags: iphone

When i am uploading app to app store i getting the following errors in Application Loader
[image]

Please help me how to solve these problems??

This is my info.plist screen

[image]

Comment: The bundle identifier has mismatch. Bundle id set for app in iTunesConnect and your `info.plist` file should match.

Comment: @Amar i am using same bundle identifier in both info.plist and iTunesConnect

Comment: Please help me its an very very urgent need of mine :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems in uploading iPhone app to app store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581548/problems-in-uploading-iphone-app-to-app-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle identifiers do not match.

App Store bundle ID is: com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio

In Info.plist it is com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}.

${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} - PRODUCT NAME set in Build Settings of your app.

So you app bundle ID looks as follows: com.kamalaminfo.jiljilradio.JilJil-Radio

I hope this will help.