# Problems in uploading iPhone app to app store?

Tags: iphone

When i am uploading  application to app store i got the following issues in application loader
[image]

Please give me suggestions?

Comment: Looks to me like those error messages are trying to tell you something. "Missing code-signing certificate" might be something to look into.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12322397/817946

Comment: @ShaggyFrog Yes but added a same bundle identifier certificates and provisioning profile

Comment: Please don't post the same question over and over.

Comment: @ShaggyFrog i am generating provisioning profile and certificates for the project testing to real devices.It's works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve issues when uploading iphone app to app store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567106/how-to-resolve-issues-when-uploading-iphone-app-to-app-store)

Comment: It can also be apple process undergoing wait patiently...

Comment: @codebreaker yes!!I tried this thing in two days.I am getting the same issues in past days too

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate app store provisioning profile with distribution certificate that is generated using code signing certificate on your current machine. I think you are submitting app from machine which is not you used to generate provisioning profile.

Comment: No i am using same machine for generating profiles and uploading to app store